# Not getting all the table data while executing the laravel query

Tags: laravel

[Link for table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc0so.png)

[link for expected result, after group by 'receiver_user_id' and recent time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUIZf.png)

I have used the laravel query:-

```
 $sub = BaseMessagesHistory::select('messages_history.*')->orderBy('created_at','DESC');

        $chats = DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub"))
            ->select('receiver_user_id',DB::raw('max(created_at) as recent_time'))
            ->where('sender_user_id',$userId)
            ->orwhere('receiver_user_id',$userId)
            ->groupBy('receiver_user_id')
            ->havingRaw('max(created_at)')
            ->latest()->get();
```

Result:-

I am getting only "recent_time" and "receiver_user_id"

Expectation:- I need whole data from table not only "recent_time" and "receiver_user_id"

So can you please help me out

Comment: any help please help me?

Comment: **I am getting only "recent_time" and "receiver_user_id"**, reason: `->select('receiver_user_id',DB::raw('max(created_at) as recent_time'))`

Comment: nevertheless, best to `->toSql()` your query to debug it.

Comment: When I am adding more than one column name into select query i am getting these error:-
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'sub.sender_user_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `receiver_user_id`, max(created_at) as recent_time, `sender_user_id`, `message`, `status` from (select `messages_history`.* from `messages_history` order by `created_at` desc) as sub where `sender_user_id` = 138 or `receiver_user_id` = 138 group by `receiver_user_id` having max(created_at) order by `created_at` desc)

Comment: any help much appriciated

Comment: *Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'sub.sender_user_id' isn't in GROUP BY* because, a group by only contains the column that being grouped.. anyway, care to elaborate on 1)how your table looked like; 2)what is your raw query; 3)expected output of the query; 4)what does calling `->toSql()` on your lengthy `DB::raw` query gave.

Answer (score 2):

It will return you only those columns which you mentioned in the select().
In your query, you mentioned only `receriver_user_id` and `recent_time`.

```
   ->select('receiver_user_id',DB::raw('max(created_at) as recent_time'))
```

You need to add all those columns in select() which you need.

Or try this `->select('sub.*',DB::raw('max(created_at) as recent_time'))`

Hope this helps. Ask in case of doubt.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'sub.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `sub`.*, max(created_at) as recent_time from (select `messages_history`.* from `messages_history` order by `created_at` desc) as sub where `sender_user_id` = 138 or `receiver_user_id` = 138 group by `receiver_user_id` having max(created_at) order by `created_at` desc)

Comment: any help please ?